# Shift the date inside a loop - python

Tags: python, yfinance

i am stuck on a silly loop that for some reason i can get the logic behind..

What i am trying to do is to download intraday data with yfinance library but it has the limitation of 60 days per request, so my idea is to create a loop to iterate a range of dates in chunks of 60 days and ultimately reconstruct a single DataFrame with all the values..
This is the code i came up so far but the results are not optimal as they contain several duplicates..

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import yfinance as yf
import time

start = datetime.strptime("2011-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
stop = datetime.strptime("2011-06-01", "%Y-%m-%d")


while start <= stop:
 time.sleep(5)  
 end = start + timedelta(days=60)
 df1.append(yf.download('^GSPC',start=start,end=end,interval='1h'))  
 start = end + timedelta(days=1)  # increase the start date by one day
```

Anyone have some suggestions or pointing me up what i am missing?

Thanks

Comment: the new start gets assigned at the end starting from last date +1 of the end date.. (if that makes sense..)

Comment: what kind of duplicates, your dates dont overlap

Comment: Nevermind guys.. i have just find out that yfinance will limit the starting days to the last 730 days of intraday data.. meaning that the range cannot be prior to this limit.. Thanks anyway for your help!